# How to use firebase's onSnapshot function conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the onSnapshot function of firebase...this is the structure of my code

```
function loadData() {
    firebaseApp
      .firestore()
      .collection("todos")
      .where("user", "==", firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .where("time", "==", time)
      .orderBy("priority", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snap) => {
       //store the data in current state
       })
    }
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, []);
```

The problem is that later in the code I am trying to update some data to firebase..So the function in onSnapshot automatically runs and reloads the data even though I don't call the loadData() function...How to prevent this triggering of onSnapshot function after every change and how to conditionally run the callback function?

Comment: Oh yes Frank thanks a lot for your help...I used the get method and it works as i expected...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to read the data once when you call `loadData`, you can use `get` instead of `onSnapshot`:

```
firebaseApp
  .firestore()
  .collection("todos")
  .where("user", "==", firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .where("time", "==", time)
  .orderBy("priority", "desc")
  .get().then((snap) => {
    //store the data in current state
  })
```

---

If you want to stop from updating the UI while you're updating the data, you have a few options:

1. Perform all updates in a [batched write or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which *may* reduce the number of calls to your `onSnapshot` callback.
2. Set a flag while you're updating the data, and clear that while you're done. Check that flag in the `onSnapshot` callback to determine whether to store the data in the state.
3. [Detach the `onSnapshot` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before you start updating the data, and then re-attach it after all updates are written.